# cuda calculations give nan after so many loops

Tags: c++, cuda

This is my first time working with cuda. I am running some calculations involving cufft and two simple kernels on an NxNxN mesh (N=128). It seems to work fine until some time between 4040 and 4050 loops, the values of my mesh points become nan. On a smaller mesh, it can complete more loops before failing. This makes me think there is a memory leak somewhere. I tried running cuda-memcheck but it returned no errors. Can you spot any problems that could be causing this? I have reduced the code to a minimum but it is still long, my apologies. Thank you for your help.

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cufft.h>
#include <cufftXt.h>
using namespace std;

__global__ void Cube (cufftComplex *data, cufftComplex *data3, int n) {

    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (i<n){
        data3[i].x = pow(data[i].x, 3);
        data3[i].y = 0;
    }
    __syncthreads();
}

__global__ void Spectral (cufftComplex *data, cufftComplex *data3, float *w, float *v, int n) {

    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;   

    if (i<n){
        data[i].x = (w[i] * data[i].x + data3[i].x * v[i]) / n;
        data[i].y = 0;
    }
    __syncthreads();
}

float ran();

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    float QQ, C;

    float tmax = 5000;
    int N = 128;
    int n = N*N*N;
    float dn = M_PI/8;
    float dt = .075;
    float psi0 = -0.175;
    float r = -0.1;

    tmax *= dt;

    //setup cuda complex arrays
    int mem_size = sizeof(cufftComplex)*n;  
    int float_mem_size = sizeof(float)*n;

    cufftComplex *h_data = (cufftComplex*)malloc(mem_size);
    cufftComplex *d_data;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_data, mem_size);

    cufftComplex *h_data3 = (cufftComplex*)malloc(mem_size);
    cufftComplex *d_data3;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_data3, mem_size);

    float * h_w = (float*)malloc(float_mem_size);   
    float *d_w;
    cudaMalloc(&d_w, float_mem_size);

    float * h_v = (float*)malloc(float_mem_size);
    float *d_v;
    cudaMalloc(&d_v, float_mem_size);

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
    h_data[i].x = psi0 + r * ran();
    h_data[i].y = 0;
    }

    int nx, ny, nz;
    float B = -4 * M_PI * M_PI / ( pow((N*dn),2));
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
    nx = (i % N);
        ny = (i / N) % N;
        nz = i / (N * N);

        if (nx > (N / 2)) {
            nx = (N - nx);
        }
        if (ny > (N / 2)) {
            ny = (N - ny);
        }
        if (nz > (N / 2)) {
            nz = (N - nz);
        }

    QQ = B * (pow(nx, 2.0) + pow(ny, 2.0) + pow(nz, 2.0));
    C = -r - 2.0 * QQ - pow(QQ, 2.0);

    h_w[i] = exp(QQ * (1.0 - C) * dt);
    h_v[i] = (h_w[i] - 1.0) / (1.0 - C);

    }

    cudaMemcpy(d_w, h_w, float_mem_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_v, h_v, float_mem_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_data, h_data, mem_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    cufftHandle plan;
    cufftPlan3d(&plan, N, N, N, CUFFT_C2C); 

    int maxThreads=(N>1024)?1024:N;
    int threadsPerBlock = maxThreads;
    int numBlocks = n/maxThreads;    

    for (float t = 0; t < tmax; t += dt) {

    Cube <<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>> (d_data, d_data3, n);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    cufftExecC2C(plan, d_data3, d_data3, CUFFT_FORWARD);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    cufftExecC2C(plan, d_data, d_data, CUFFT_FORWARD);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    Spectral <<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>> (d_data, d_data3, d_w, d_v, n);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    cufftExecC2C(plan, d_data, d_data, CUFFT_INVERSE);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

}

    //check output (should be a number)
    cudaMemcpy(h_data, d_data, mem_size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cout <<h_data[0].x <<endl;

    //clean up
    cufftDestroy(plan);
    cudaFree(d_data);
    cudaFree(d_data3);
    cudaFree(d_w);
    cudaFree(d_v);
    free(h_w);
    free(h_v);
    free(h_data);
    free(h_data3);

    return 0;
}

float ran(){    //random in range [-1,1]
    float u= float (rand())/(RAND_MAX);
    //return round(u);
    return 2*u-1;
}
```

Comment: The division by `(1.0 - C)` seems to stick out. What prevents it from becoming zero?

Comment: I run the same calculations in an MPI routine with no problems.

Comment: That doesn't prove much. Even though modern compilers try to avoid such problems as much as possible, tiny variations in floating point numbers can come from the smallest alteration (that may change the order floating point operations are performed), let alone a change in the compiler used.

Comment: I see what you mean. The smallest value of (1-C) is 0.00234365 and the largest value of h_v[i] is 0.154915. These are constant and they don't seem likely to cause nans on their own.

Comment: There is really not that much code here.  In your cuda kernels, instrument every single read of a floating point quantity and every single generation of a floating point quantity with a CUDA [isnan](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__SINGLE.html#group__CUDA__MATH__SINGLE_1gf8093cd7c372f91c9837a82fd368c711) test.  Then you'll know if the first instance is arising out of your cuda kernels or out of host or cublas code.  If it is arising from CUDA kernels, then identifying the function and the arguments that give rise to it will probably be instructive.

Comment: If it is arising out of host or cublas code, use a similar methodology to work backwards to finding the source of the nan.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I am attempting to use the isnan function but it is giving me weird results. For the following snippet inside my Spectral kernel, the nan is not detected until the final line. But the output tells me that g is a nan, meaning data3 is a nan, and both g and data3 went undetected.

    if(isnan(v[i])){printf("v %i %f ", i, t);}
    if(isnan(data3[i].x)){printf("d %i %f ", i, t);}
    float g = data3[i].x * v[i];
    if(isnan(g)){printf("g2 %i %f ", i, t);} 
    data[i].x = f + g;
    if(isnan(data[i].x)){printf("e %i %f %f %f ", i, f, g, t);}

Comment: According to my testing, the code always fails on iteration 4860 of the main loop. Within this loop, the `d_data3` array is containing `nan` values when it is read in by the `Spectral` kernel. Therefore, it seems evident to me that the `cufftExecC2C` call prior to that on `d_data3` is producing `nan` values.  That's as far as I have gotten so far. The next step would be to detect this condition, and spit out the input and output arrays for that particular call, and look for suspicious data.  The first value in a forward FFT is the DC component, which is the sum of all inputs. This can overflow

Comment: I'm seeing what may be the same issue with CUDA 11.5. Using multiple streams to process a large number of data channels, I get good results the first time I iterate over all the streams, then the results start to diverge from truth. Then I get some INF values and finally NaN values. The first so many values in each batch (i.e. row) of a single op are good. The rest are NaN. It only occurs when performing in-place transforms. Switching from in-place fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my instrumentation of your code so far.  When I enabled the device assert in `my_assert`, it indicated that d_data3 input at the `nan5` point was failing (i.e. it was `nan`).  That indicated that the cufftExecC2C call on `d_data3` immmediately prior was producing `nan` data.  If you have invalid inputs, I believe an FFT can produce out-of-range results.

The code is instrumented to allow you to dump the data and look at it.  You will have to modify `dump_data` to display whatever it is you wish to see.

When I run the code below, it eventually prints out:

```
4850.14
4851.14
4852.14
4853.14
4854.14
4855.14
4856.14
4857.14
4858.14
4859.14
4860.14
d_data3 output nan check failed
$
```

So the `nan` first occurs on iteration 4860, and the `d_data3` input check did not fail, so the `nan` occurs in `d_data3` as a result of the FFT operation in loop iteration 4860.  You'll need to study the input and output data to see if you can determine why.  There may be some modification to the `d_data3` data in the `Cube` kernel that is causing this.  For example, since you are repetitively cubing the data, doesn't it seem reasonable at some point that it would exceed `float` range?

Here's my instrumented code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cufft.h>
#include <cufftXt.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

__host__ __device__ void my_assert(bool cond){

  //assert(cond);

}

__global__ void Cube (cufftComplex *data, cufftComplex *data3, int n) {

    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (i<n){
        float temp = data[i].x;
        if (isnan(temp)) {printf("nan1: %d\n", i); my_assert(0);}
        data3[i].x = pow(data[i].x, 3);
        if (isnan(data3[i].x)) {printf("nan2: %d %f\n", i, data[i].x); my_assert(0);}
        data3[i].y = 0;
    }
    __syncthreads();
}

__global__ void Spectral (cufftComplex *data, cufftComplex *data3, float *w, float *v, int n) {

    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (i<n){
        float temp1 = w[i];
        if (isnan(temp1)) {printf("nan3: %d\n", i); my_assert(0);}
        float temp2 = data[i].x;
        if (isnan(temp2)) {printf("nan4: %d\n", i); my_assert(0);}
        float temp3 = data3[i].x;
        if (isnan(temp3)) {printf("nan5: %d\n", i); my_assert(0);}
        float temp4 = v[i];
        if (isnan(temp4)) {printf("nan6: %d\n", i); my_assert(0);}

        data[i].x = (w[i] * data[i].x + data3[i].x * v[i]) / n;
        if (isnan(data[i].x)) {printf("nan7: %d, %f, %f, %f, %f, %d\n",i, temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, n); my_assert(0);}
        data[i].y = 0;
    }
    __syncthreads();
}


__global__  void nan_kernel(cufftComplex *d, int len, bool *res){
  int idx=threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  if (idx < len)
    if (isnan(d[idx].x) || isnan(d[idx].y)) *res = true;
}
bool *d_nan;

bool checknan(cufftComplex *d, int len){
  bool h_nan = false;
  cudaMemcpy(d_nan, &h_nan, sizeof(bool), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  nan_kernel<<<(len/1024)+1, 1024>>>(d, len, d_nan);
  cudaMemcpy(&h_nan, d_nan, sizeof(bool), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  return h_nan;
}

void dump_data(cufftComplex *d1, cufftComplex *d2, int len)
{
 // add code here to spit out the data however you would like to see it
 // perhaps to a file
 std::cout << "input:         output: " << std::endl;
 for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
   std::cout << d1[i].x << "," << d1[i].y << "  " << d2[i].x << "," << d2[i].y << std::endl;

};

float ran();

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    float QQ, C;

    float tmax = 5000;
    int N = 128;
    int n = N*N*N;
    float dn = M_PI/8;
    float dt = .075;
    float psi0 = -0.175;
    float r = -0.1;

    tmax *= dt;

    //setup cuda complex arrays
    int mem_size = sizeof(cufftComplex)*n;
    int float_mem_size = sizeof(float)*n;

    cufftComplex *h_data = (cufftComplex*)malloc(mem_size);
    cufftComplex *d_data;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_data, mem_size);

    cufftComplex *h_data3 = (cufftComplex*)malloc(mem_size);
    cufftComplex *d_data3;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_data3, mem_size);

    float * h_w = (float*)malloc(float_mem_size);
    float *d_w;
    cudaMalloc(&d_w, float_mem_size);

    float * h_v = (float*)malloc(float_mem_size);
    float *d_v;
    cudaMalloc(&d_v, float_mem_size);

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
      h_data[i].x = psi0 + r * ran();
      h_data[i].y = 0;
    }

    int nx, ny, nz;
    float B = -4 * M_PI * M_PI / ( pow((N*dn),2));
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        nx = (i % N);
        ny = (i / N) % N;
        nz = i / (N * N);

        if (nx > (N / 2)) {
            nx = (N - nx);
        }
        if (ny > (N / 2)) {
            ny = (N - ny);
        }
        if (nz > (N / 2)) {
            nz = (N - nz);
        }

        QQ = B * (pow(nx, 2.0) + pow(ny, 2.0) + pow(nz, 2.0));
        C = -r - 2.0 * QQ - pow(QQ, 2.0);

        h_w[i] = exp(QQ * (1.0 - C) * dt);
        h_v[i] = (h_w[i] - 1.0) / (1.0 - C);

    }

    cudaMemcpy(d_w, h_w, float_mem_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_v, h_v, float_mem_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_data, h_data, mem_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    cufftHandle plan;
    cufftPlan3d(&plan, N, N, N, CUFFT_C2C);

    int maxThreads=(N>1024)?1024:N;
    int threadsPerBlock = maxThreads;
    int numBlocks = n/maxThreads;
    cufftResult res;
    cudaMalloc(&d_nan, sizeof(bool));
    cufftComplex *i3, *o3;
    i3 = (cufftComplex *)malloc(mem_size);
    o3 = (cufftComplex *)malloc(mem_size);
    std::cout << "start loop" << std::endl;
    for (float t = 0; t < tmax; t += dt) {
      std::cout << t/dt << std::endl;
      Cube <<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>> (d_data, d_data3, n);
      cudaDeviceSynchronize();
      cudaMemcpy(i3, d_data3, mem_size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
      if (checknan(d_data3, n)) {std::cout << "d_data3 input nan check failed" << std::endl; return -1;}
      res = cufftExecC2C(plan, d_data3, d_data3, CUFFT_FORWARD);
      if (res != CUFFT_SUCCESS) {std::cout << "cufft1 error: " << (int)res << " , " << t/dt << std::endl; return 1;}
      cudaDeviceSynchronize();
      if (checknan(d_data3, n)) {std::cout << "d_data3 output nan check failed" << std::endl; cudaMemcpy(o3, d_data3, mem_size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost); dump_data(i3, o3, n); return -1;}

      res = cufftExecC2C(plan, d_data, d_data, CUFFT_FORWARD);
      if (res != CUFFT_SUCCESS) {std::cout << "cufft2 error: " << (int)res << " , " << t/dt << std::endl; return 1;}
      cudaDeviceSynchronize();

      Spectral <<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>> (d_data, d_data3, d_w, d_v, n);
      cudaDeviceSynchronize();

      res = cufftExecC2C(plan, d_data, d_data, CUFFT_INVERSE);
      if (res != CUFFT_SUCCESS) {std::cout << "cufft3 error: " << (int)res << " , " << t/dt << std::endl; return 1;}
      cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    }

    //check output (should be a number)
    cudaMemcpy(h_data, d_data, mem_size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cout <<h_data[0].x <<endl;
    cudaError_t cres = cudaGetLastError();
    if (cres != cudaSuccess) std::cout << "cuda error: " << cudaGetErrorString(cres) << std::endl;
    //clean up
    cufftDestroy(plan);
    cudaFree(d_data);
    cudaFree(d_data3);
    cudaFree(d_w);
    cudaFree(d_v);
    free(h_w);
    free(h_v);
    free(h_data);
    free(h_data3);

    return 0;
}

float ran(){    //random in range [-1,1]
    float u= float (rand())/(RAND_MAX);
    //return round(u);
    return 2*u-1;
}
```

EDIT:
After some addition of printout code to `dump_data` (see modification above) I see this:

```
...
4859.14
4860.14
d_data3 output nan check failed
input:         output:
3.37127e+19,0  nan,nan
3.21072e+19,0  nan,nan
2.76453e+19,0  nan,nan
2.13248e+19,0  nan,nan
1.44669e+19,0  nan,nan
8.37214e+18,0  nan,nan
3.93645e+18,0  nan,nan
1.35501e+18,0  nan,nan
2.55741e+17,0  nan,nan
5.96468e+15,0  nan,nan
-1.36656e+16,0  nan,nan
-2.33688e+17,0  nan,nan
-8.37407e+17,0  nan,nan
-1.79915e+18,0  nan,nan
-2.96302e+18,0  nan,nan
-4.11485e+18,0  nan,nan
-5.03876e+18,0  nan,nan
-5.57617e+18,0  nan,nan
-5.65307e+18,0  nan,nan
-5.28957e+18,0  nan,nan
-4.5872e+18,0  nan,nan
-3.68309e+18,0  nan,nan
...
```

I'm not an FFT expert, but it might be the case that if you do an FFT on a large array filled with large values, using `float` precision, that overflow may occur.  If you only need to get to 5000 iterations and you're failing at 4860, you might get there if you change all your datatypes to `double` from `float`, but I'm not sure about the numerical sense of what you are doing here.

Finally, note that both [cufft](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/index.html#cufft-transform-directions) and [fftw](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/The-1d-Discrete-Fourier-Transform-_0028DFT_0029.html#The-1d-Discrete-Fourier-Transform-_0028DFT_0029) perform un-normalized transforms.  This may be playing a role in the seeming growth of magnitudes in your data set.  As I stated already, I'm not familiar with the arithmetic or algorithm you are trying to implement here.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed assistance. 
The algorithm is designed to keep the array values around +/-1. 
In the posted code, the normalization is taken care of in the Spectral kernel by the division by n. But this got me thinking. Since n is large and data[i].x could be very small (in fourier space), I could imagine overflows resulting from this operation. I split the normalization into its own kernel and executed it after the final C2C transform (so it works on the real space values, which are guaranteed to be nice). I also made sure to set data[i].y = 0.0f. These steps fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have a float underflow happening around iteration 4040? Taking the cube of your data3 would lead me to check out that possibility. It is pretty easy to spiral into an underflow on a float32 if your not careful. You could throw a check in there to limit your value to some minimum epsilon to prevent this.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I added a check in my Cube kernel for data and data3 as so, but it did not fix the problem:
if ((data[i].x > 0 and data[i].x < 0.0000000001) or (data[i].x < 0 and data[i].x > -0.0000000001)){
     data[i].x = 0;  
 }